# is a javascript function inside of a function globally scoped?

Tags: javascript, oop

Here is an example of the test that I did:

```
function f1(var1){
  alert('f1 called');
  function f2(var2){
    alert('f2 called');

  }
  this.data='something else';
  this.f2 = f2;
}
f1.data='something';
f1.f3 = function(var3){
    alert('f3 called');
}
console.log(f1); //shows the function
console.log(f1.data); //can have properties attached - cool
console.log(f1.f2(2)); //error: "f1.f2" is not a function
console.log(f1.f3(3)); //this works as expected
```

It appears that the function `f2` inside f1 is local in scope.  is there any equivalent way to call a function inside a function like this?

Comment: assign it like this: `this.f2 = function() { //...`!

Comment: You need to expose it to global scope, e.g., use any one of the JS module patterns. But the whole point of scoping a function locally is to *avoid* polluting the global scope. What's your end goal?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ... That's what `this.f2 = f2` would do; there's no difference.

Comment: To access the properties defined with `this`, you should use the `new` keyword to create an object.

Comment: You need an instance, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/fwyeopww/

Comment: @DaveNewton ooops didn't see that line!

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, `this` is bound to the global scope of `window` because you haven't instantiated an instance of `f1` using `new f1();`

```
var f = new f1();
f.f2(); // Now works
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there are a couple of patterns you can use to access the `f2` function outside of `f1`. You can instantiate an `f1` object using `new`:

```
function f1() {
  this.f2 = function () { console.log('f2'); }
}

new f1().f2() //logs 'f2'
```

Or you can return the function `f2` from the function `f1`:

```
function f1() {
  return function f2() { console.log('f2'); }
}

f1()() //logs 'f2'
```

Answer (score 0):

change code to:

```
function f1 (var1){
  alert('f1 called');           
};
f1.data='something else';
f1.f2 = function f2(var2){
  alert('f2 called');
};
```